# Result of query is `Model::ActiveRecord_Relation`. How can I call ActiveRecord methods (eg. `.where`) on it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm struggling to understand why I'm unable to call `.where` on the results of what looks to be an ActiveRecord query.

I'm dipping down into SQL a bit to create virtual columns for matching. We have two models: `Organization` and `Subscription`. My query to fetch orgs with subscriptions is as follows:

```rb
def orgs_with_plans
  subquery = Subscription.select("DISTINCT ON (organization_id) *")
    .order(:organization_id, created_at: :desc)

  Organization
    .joins("LEFT JOIN (#{subquery.to_sql}) AS subscription_data ON organizations.id = subscription_data.organization_id")
    .select("
      organizations.*,
      (CASE
        WHEN subscription_data.id IS NULL THEN
          (CASE
            WHEN organizations.trial_end_date > CURRENT_DATE THEN 'trial'
            ELSE 'expired'
          END)
        ELSE subscription_data.plan_name
      END) AS plan_name
    ")
end
```

I can successfully get `plan_name` when I call the following:

```rb
orgs_with_plans.each do |org|
  puts "orgname: #{org.name}, plan name: #{org.plan_name}"
end
```

Additionally, the output sql of `orgs_with_plans.to_sql` runs as expected in my DB.

If I try to call `orgs_with_plans.where('plan_name = ?', 'trial')`, I run into an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
  LINE 10:         END) AS plan_name
```

Why is this invalid syntax when I use `count` but totally fine otherwise?

Comment: When you run your where clause, have you tried `to_sql` on it to see what it’s generating that’s invalid?

Comment: @MarkG. i have but it fails with the "StatementInvalid" error as soon as I put the `.where` on it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When you are referring to `plan_name` inside the `where`, Rails is looking for a column named `plan_name`, which is not there. If you want to use the alias `plan_name` in the `where` condition, you gonna need [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

You have to update your code a bit to make `orgs_with_plans.where('plan_name = ?', 'trial')` work:

```
def orgs_with_trial_plans
  orgs_with_trial_plans = <<~SQL
    WITH orgs_with_plans AS
    (
      #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql(orgs_with_plans.to_sql)}
    )
    SELECT name, plan_name
    FROM orgs_with_plans
    WHERE plan_name = 'trial'
  SQL

  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(orgs_with_trial_plans).to_a
end
```

Or if you don't want to use SQL, you could use `select` to filter out `plan_name`s with `trial`

```
orgs_with_trial.select { |org| org.plan_name == 'trial' }
```

Hope this helps!